# Snapping feature nodes doesn't work after feature creation (filter involved)

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing, features, feature-layer

I've experienced a strange behaviour during editing mode:

1. I have set a filter to 2 features (polygons), part of on of my PostGIS layers: `"name"='A' OR "name"='B'`
2. After that I have created a new feature with the `name='C'`
3. After saving the layer edits, the new feature logically disappears due to the filter
4. So I have extended my filter to the new feature (all 3 features appear now in the canvas): `"name"='A' OR "name"='B' "name"='C'`

When I now want to edit the new feature it is not possible to snap to any node of the new feature.
'Identify Feature' and the 'Moving Feature' tools are working.

Strange, after moving the feature the node snapping works.

**EDIT**

When I define the filter `"name"='A' OR "name"='B' "name"='C'` a priori, before I create the new polygon with the name='C', it works.

Is this an expectable behaviour or a kind of bug?

I'm working with QGIS 2.8 on a Linux Mint virtual machine.

Comment: What kind of file do you use ? Cause from my experience, its not possible at all to edit shp files features when filtered. Or do you mean rule-based rendering? In spatialite, editing filtered data is still possible btw.

Comment: I've edited my question.I'm working with PostgreSQL/PostGIS layers.